# When importing logisticregression from sklearn.linear_model I suddenly get an attributeError?

Tags: scikit-learn, logistic-regression, attributeerror

> import sklearn
>
> from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression

The import works, but then from the second line I get this error. Other sklearn packages such as model_selection and metrics do work. Anyone can help?

> `AttributeError: module 'numpy' has no attribute 'float'.`  np.float`was a deprecated alias for the builtin`float`. To avoid this error in existing code, use` float`by itself. Doing this will not modify any behavior and is safe. If you specifically wanted the numpy scalar type, use`np.float64`here. The aliases was originally deprecated in NumPy 1.20; for more details and guidance see the original release note at: https://numpy.org/devdocs/release/1.20.0-notes.html#deprecations`

I tried updating numpy package and uninstalling sklearn and installing again. Nothing helps..

Comment: You probably need to _downgrade_ numpy or _upgrade_ sklearn. Providing the full error traceback and versions of those would help diagnose.